# how to create htaccess for website

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am a newbie for htaccess.
Want to create a htaccess file for my website

I want to show following link

```
http://mysite.com/show-post.php?postId=23423423
```

in following format

```
http://mysite.com/post/23423423
```

can anybody tell me what will be the content for the .htaccess file

My Exact urls are

```
http://localhost/pinboard/show-post.php?postId=5635sdf43535452
```

and I want to convert it to 
    http://localhost/pinboard/post/5635sdf43535452

regards

Comment: btw, you should add 'apache' to your tags, because .htaccess doesn't really mean a lot (you can put this directive in other files, like the virtual host definition...)

Comment: Hi rohitpurohit! You hsould take a moment to revisit your previous questions and accept an answer where you can (using the big check mark next to it). It's the polite thing to do on StackOverflow. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `RewriteRule` with *regular expressions*. Your `.htaccess` should look something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /post.php?postId=(.*) /post/$1 [NC]
```

Check [this site](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php) for more detailed instructions.

Comment: Please check my post , i have edited it and then give me an exact htaccess. I have tried your one but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn RewriteRule directives.
It should look like that (that's untested, it's just to give you a hint)
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /show-post.php?postId=(.*) /post/$1

Answer (score 0):

I cannot fail to notice that you have a dismal record of accepting your answers. Please start accepting some of the previous answers as a courtesy to the members who took time to answer your questions.

For this current question use this code in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?post/(.*)$ $1show-post.php?postId=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```